# are STORE_NAME and STORE_GLOBAL equivalent in main scope?

Tags: python, module, scope, bytecode

I guess I am a bit confused about the module namespace in Python.
I played with Byteplay and that's what I have tried :

1. I built a list of opcodes equivalent to : (byteplay's printcodelist) ->

   ```
   0 LOAD_CONST           3
   1 STORE_NAME           a
   2 LOAD_CONST           None
   3 RETURN_VALUE
   ```

   However when I exec it like that :

   ```
   exec mycode in t #t is {} 
   print 'a' in t #False , but I expected True
   ```

   the same happens when I

   ```
   import b 
   'a' in b.__dict__ #False
   b.a #error
   ```

   When I replace

   ```
    STORE_NAME
   ```

   with

   ```
    STORE_GLOBAL
   ```

   it works.However I thought STORE_NAME is used to store a value in the current local namespace.But isn't the local namespace on the top-level the same as the global namespace ? 
   For example

   ```
   locals() == globals()
   ```

   is true in the main scope if it's only used.

   Basicly : 
   if I compile "a = 3" with the built in compile function ,

   ```
   dis.dis() and bytecode's Code.from_code(codeobject) show STORE_NAME
   ```

   .
   Hm

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to reproduce your steps and everything worked fine for me. Let's see the process step-by-step. First of all, code creation.

Here we import all we need:

```
from byteplay import Code, LOAD_CONST, STORE_NAME, RETURN_VALUE
```

Let's create a list of opcodes with appropriate parameters (a list of tuples, each containing opcode as a first element and argument as a second one):

```
lst = [
    (LOAD_CONST, 3),
    (STORE_NAME, 'a'),
    (LOAD_CONST, None),
    (RETURN_VALUE, None)
]
```

Okay, done with that. Next, the most responsible step is a Code object creation. It receives **10 arguments**. Let's look through:

```
x = Code(
    lst,   # opcodes list (what we execute)
    [],    # outer scope variables (obviously, we don't have any here),
    [],    # arguments (nothing here),
    False, # *args here? Nope
    False, # **kwargs here? Nope
    False, # !!!Important!!! DO WE CREATE NEW NAMESPACE? No! We use given!
    '',    # name ...
    '',    # filename ... who cares...
    0,     # first line number
    ''     # docstring
)
```

> **Attention!** If the 6-th argument to code creation was set to True, you won't receive 'a' variable stored in locals after our code is executed. That's how functions work. They create their own namespace (co_names), and namespace we execute code in won't be patched with 'a' variable.

So, let's run it!

```
nsloc = {}   # locals to execute code with
nsglob = {}  # globals to execute code with

# We could use one namespace for both but that doesn't matter

exec x.to_code() in nsglob, nsloc

print nsloc
```

And, the result is as expected:

```
{'a': 3}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: I am not sure why I haven't voted for this 10 years ago: thank you!